# Socket.IO not connecting from web browser

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to build live location tracking using socket and nodejs

but i am unable to connect to websocket using socket.io below is the code of node js server

````
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const express = require('express');

var app = require('express')();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('path.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('path/cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('path/cert.pem'),
  requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};


var io = require('socket.io')(https, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://aayo.express:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendfile('index.html');
});

//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
   console.log('A user connected');

   setTimeout(function() {
      //Sending an object when emmiting an event
      socket.emit('testerEvent', { description: 'A custom event named testerEvent!'});
   }, 4000);


   socket.on('clientEvent', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
   
   //Whenever someone disconnects this piece of code executed
   socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('A user disconnected');
   });
});

// http.listen(3000, function() {
//    console.log('listening on *:3000');
// });

https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end("hello world\n");
  console.log(req);
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
}).listen(3000);```
````

below is my html file

```
@extends(backpack_view('blank'))

@section('after_styles')
    <!-- Web Fonts 
  ================================================== -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('frontend/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('frontend/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('frontend/css/ionicons.min.css')}}"/>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('frontend/css/owl.carousel.css')}}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('frontend/css/owl.transitions.css')}}"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('frontend/css/style.css')}}"/> -->

@endsection



@section('content')
<div class="loader">
  <div class="loader__figure"></div>
</div>


<!-- Nav and Logo
    ================================================== -->

<iframe src="https://aayo.express:3000"></iframe>


<!-- Primary Page Layout
    ================================================== -->

<div class="section full-height over-hide"> 
  <div id="map" class="" style="width:100%;height:600px;"></div>
  <div class="tracking-info"> 
      <ul>
        <li><b>Driver Name: </b> Subash Rijal </li>
        <li><b>Phone no.</b> 0123456789</li>
        <li><b>Distance: </b> 5km</li>
      </ul>
  </div>  
</div>


<!-- Modal --> 
@endsection

@section('after_scripts')
<!-- JAVASCRIPT
    ================================================== --> 
<script src="{{asset('frontend/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script> 
<script src="{{asset('frontend/js/popper.min.js')}}"></script> 
<script src="{{asset('frontend/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script> 
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCcI96mdv1eVkGj4p3L61Xyri_SFUNA3xI&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="{{asset('frontend/js/plugins.js')}}"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.0.5/socket.io.min.js'"></script> -->
<script src="{{asset('js/socket.io.js')}}"></script>

<script src="{{asset('js/live-location.js')}}"></script> 
<script src="{{asset('frontend/js/custom.js')}}"></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
var mapProp= {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
  zoom:5,
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapProp);
}
</script>
 
<script>
  
</script>
 
<!-- End Document
================================================== -->
@endsection
```

how can i solve this? i am using nodejs, and server code to run it

if you have any experience in it could you please help me to solve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Please check your client and server side socket.io versions which they should be same. And on the server side check the getting started example with express your connection is kinda wrong, you gave directly https package to io as argument. https://socket.io/get-started/chat maybe check this as an example

Comment: both server and client version are same.

Comment: Like I said check those and fix your server side code. while creating io you can't pass https package all together it's expecting a created http/s-server.